# Karate Date Filter based on createdDate which includes the Time as well

Tags: karate

I have a response as

- def responselist =

  [
  {
  "createdDate": "2023-10-27T15:17:51.000+00:00",
  "createdTime": "09:17:50"
  },
  {
  "createdDate": "2023-10-28T14:08:33.000+00:00",
  "createdTime": "08:08:32"
  },
  {
  "createdDate": "2023-10-28T14:08:39.000+00:00",
  "createdTime": "08:08:39"
  },
  {
  "createdDate": "2023-10-28T14:08:43.000+00:00",
  "createdTime": "08:08:49"
  }
  ]
  i want to filter data based on createdDate and fetch the latest createdDate data it should include time as well.